# Execute program in C and don't wait it for finish

Tags: c, windows

I would like to call a program in C on Windows and immediately close the main program. I've tried using `system()` like this:

```
system("SecondaryProgram.exe");
return 0;
```

But the "caller" program always waits for `SecondaryProgram.exe` to finish. I would like to avoid this and immediately return 0 before the "called" program closes, something like opening it in "another thread". Is there any other function that does this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: If you're on POSIX, you can `execve()` the second program.

Comment: *BTW, I think I'm being very clear.* I'm certain everyone that posts here thinks they are as well. The question is whether or not your readers think so.

Comment: @Logicrat Windows, sorry. Updated.

Comment: If post is for "Window" only, suggest adding `Windows` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Windows compilers have support for `execXXX` and `spawnXXX` functions. So something like this should work:

```
#include <process.h>
...
spawnl(P_NOWAIT, "prog.exe", "prog.exe", NULL);
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CreateProcess**() API. When it successfully launches another process, it will return a handle to you that you can use to wait for the process to complete, or not, as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("cmd.exe /C SecondaryProgram.exe");
```

But you may have a DOS box floating around until SecondaryProgram finishes.